# fuel.gazebosim.org down or deprecated?

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to run the [ROS / Gazebo tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Gazebo.html).

So I downloaded [visualize_lidar.sdf](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-sim/blob/main/examples/worlds/visualize_lidar.sdf) and run as instructed:

`ign gazebo -v 4 -r visualize_lidar.sdf`

**Small issue:** there's an error message:

`Error [Converter.cc:156] Unable to convert from SDF version 1.10 to 1.9`

I "fixed" this by changing the version in the sdf file to 1.9.

**Main issue:**

This part of the sdf file fails:

```
<include>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 1.57</pose>
  <uri>https://fuel.gazebosim.org/1.0/openrobotics/models/Playground</uri>
</include>
```

which is obvious as `https://fuel.gazebosim.org/` returns `404 page not found`.

--> Is this a temporary issue? Or is fuel.gazebosim.org deprecated?

I found the model on `https://app.gazebosim.org/` and tried to change the sdf file as follows, but that doesn't work either:

```
<include>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 1.57</pose>
  <uri>https://app.gazebosim.org/OpenRobotics/fuel/models/Playground</uri>
</include>
```

Fails with following error:

```
`[Err] [Server.cc:139] Error Code 13: [/sdf/world[@name="visualize_lidar_world"]/include[0]/uri:/home/johan/gazebo_test/src/tutorial/visualize_lidar.sdf:L516]: Msg: Unable to find uri[https://app.gazebosim.org/OpenRobotics/fuel/models/Playground]`
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28912/fuel.gazebosim.org-down-or-deprecated?/) by [jrtg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/156210/jrtg/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 31 on 2023-03-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [azeey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6889/azeey/) on 2023-03-22**:
Can you tell us what version of Gazebo you're using? Also, https://fuel.gazebosim.org/ is the correct url. It returns a 404 when using a web browser, but if you go to https://fuel.gazebosim.org/1.0/openrobotics/models/Playground, it'll respond with some data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> Can you tell us what version of Gazebo you're using?

It's Ignition Gazebo Fortress, installed from packages on an Ubuntu 22.04 in a virtualbox on Windows.

Today it does load the model, so I think this must have been a temporary server-side issue (I'm fairly sure I also got the 404 with the full path).

It still doesn't work though (complains about several libraries not found).

In the mean time I have compiled Gazebo Garden and Rolling from source, as well as the ros_gz_bridge (and for the latter also gps_msgs).

This seems to work, except that the bridge errors:

`[WARN] [1679564767.107537388] [ros_gz_bridge]: Failed to create a bridge for topic [/model/vehicle_blue/cmd_vel] with ROS2 type [geometry_msgs/msg/Twist] to topic [/model/vehicle_blue/cmd_vel] with Gazebo Transport type [ignition.msgs.Twist]`

This seems rather obvious, as there is no topic `cmd_vel`? Although it's not listed in the [official tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Advanced/Simulators/Gazebo.html) either?

```
ign topic -l
/clock
/gazebo/resource_paths
/gui/camera/pose
/model/vehicle_blue/odometry
/model/vehicle_blue/tf
/stats
/world/visualize_lidar_world/clock
/world/visualize_lidar_world/dynamic_pose/info
/world/visualize_lidar_world/pose/info
/world/visualize_lidar_world/scene/deletion
/world/visualize_lidar_world/scene/info
/world/visualize_lidar_world/state
/world/visualize_lidar_world/stats`
```

EDIT: I learned that:

1. Contrary to ROS 2, topics that have listeners only are not shown in `gz topic -l`. This will thankfully be [fixed soon](https://github.com/gazebosim/gz-transport/pull/379).
2. Obviously  the bridge command failed, as `ignition.msgs.Twist` has been renamed to `gz.msgs.Twist`.

It is working now, thank you.

---

Originally posted by [jrtg](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/156210/jrtg/) with karma: 31 on 2023-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0